# Series not dropped although curl response from InfluxDB is HTTP 200

Tags: curl, influxdb

I am trying to use `DROP SERIES` along with the `WITH` statement in InfluxDB. I wish to drop some values using the following query:

```
DROP SERIES FROM "measurement_name" WHERE "tag_name"='tag_value'
```

I my case for a test, it should drop all the values from the measurement since I do not have distinct tags.

#### cURL

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=testNimble' --data-urlencode 'q=drop series from "pressure" where "unit"='hPa''
```

#### Response on InfluxDB Daemon

```
2019-03-18T18:36:37.818018Z     info    Executing query {"log_id": "0EGWa~nl000", "service": "query", "query": "DROP SERIES FROM pressure WHERE unit = hPa"}
[httpd] 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2019:19:36:37 +0100] "POST /query?db=testNimble HTTP/1.1" 200 33 "-" "curl/7.35.0" c3b5ba54-49ac-11e9-800e-000000000000 0
```

#### Reponse from HTTP

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: ebd5b2a4-49ab-11e9-800b-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.6.1
X-Request-Id: ebd5b2a4-49ab-11e9-800b-000000000000
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 18:30:35 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"results":[{"statement_id":0}]}
```

However the data still exists:

```
select * from pressure limit 10

name: pressure
time                unit v
----                ---- -
1545153813714000000 hPa  101997
1545153814761000000 hPa  102004
1545153816045000000 hPa  102006
1545153817203000000 hPa  102003
1545153818265000000 hPa  102003
1545153819446000000 hPa  102003
1545153820498000000 hPa  102004
1545153821680000000 hPa  102007
1545153822854000000 hPa  102003
1545153823904000000 hPa  102003
```

I tried restarting the daemon but the data still exists.

### InfluxD Log

It mentions the that I am trying to query this

```
 "query": "DROP SERIES FROM pressure WHERE unit = hPa"
```

The Double Quotes and single quotes are not being escaped here.

I tried changing my query with escape for quotes as follows:

```
 curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=test' --data-urlencode 'q=DROP SERIES WHERE "unit"=\'hPa\' '
```

it then asks for an extra single quote (WHY? all the quotes are closed)

and the reponse throws an error:

```
{"error":"error parsing query: found \\, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 26"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue in WSL by using the multi-line formatting for bash as follows:

```
curl -i -XPOST \
> 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=test' \
> --date-urlencode \
> "q=DROP SERIES FROM WHERE "unit"='hPa'"
```